# SQL Server: why 'SPARSE' does not impact for a space?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sparse-columns

Why alter table <> alter column<> SPARSE does not have an effect in cases 1-3 but only in case 4?
I.e. can we say that column can be declared as SPARSE only when creating?

I have tested this code in SQL2012.

```
-- 1
CREATE TABLE UnSparsed(ID INT IDENTITY(1,1),
FirstCol INT,
SecondCol VARCHAR(100),
ThirdCol SmallDateTime)
GO

INSERT INTO UnSparsed SELECT TOP 50000 NULL,NULL, NULL
FROM master..spt_values v1, 
     master..spt_values v2

GO
sp_spaceused 'UnSparsed'
GO
--- 2
alter table UnSparsed alter column FirstCol int SPARSE NULL
alter table UnSparsed alter column SecondCol VARCHAR(100) SPARSE NULL
alter table UnSparsed alter column ThirdCol SmallDateTime  SPARSE NULL
GO
sp_spaceused 'UnSparsed'
GO
--- 3
truncate table UnSparsed
GO
INSERT INTO UnSparsed SELECT TOP 50000 NULL,NULL, NULL
FROM master..spt_values v1, 
     master..spt_values v2

GO
sp_spaceused 'UnSparsed'
GO
DROP TABLE UnSparsed
GO
--- 4
CREATE TABLE UnSparsed(ID INT IDENTITY(1,1),
FirstCol INT SPARSE NULL,
SecondCol VARCHAR(100)  SPARSE NULL,
ThirdCol SmallDateTime  SPARSE NULL)
GO
INSERT INTO UnSparsed SELECT TOP 50000 NULL,NULL, NULL
FROM master..spt_values v1, 
     master..spt_values v2

GO
sp_spaceused 'UnSparsed'
GO
```

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding SPARSE made table much bigger](http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/12256/3690)

Comment: Though in your case you have no clustered index to `REBUILD` so would need to recreate the table or add and drop a CI.

Comment: I have some large tables and want to apply property 'sparse' to some of really sparse columns. Does it mean it is not always reduce the existing table space?

Comment: @Oleg, SPARSE is only needed on fixed-width columns to allow them to not take up that amount of space when set to NULL; it is _not_ needed on variable-width columns (i.e. your `SecondCol VARCHAR(100)`) as they naturally don't take up any space when empty.

Comment: Yes, thank you, I see. I have some tables with many uniqueidentifier fields containing nulls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems need to do

```
ALTER TABLE t REBUILD;
```

after this action all is ok.